# Display Post from specific category without changing layout

Tags: wordpress

I want to display post from specific category

```
<?php get_header();

get_template_part( 'content/archive-header' ); ?>
<div id="loop-container" class="loop-container">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('post_type' =>'post','post_status' =>'publish','cat' =>'30606','paged' =>$paged);
    $arr_posts =  new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
            $arr_posts->the_post();
            ct_mission_news_get_content_template();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
</div>

<?php // Output pagination if Jetpack not installed, otherwise check if infinite scroll is active before outputting
if ( !class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) ) {
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'mid_size' => 5
    ) );
} elseif ( !Jetpack::is_module_active( 'infinite-scroll' ) ) {
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'mid_size' => 5
    ) );
}
get_footer();
```

when i used above code theme layout changed i want same layout as per theme.

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: Mission News theme with double layout

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Instead using `category id` use `category name`.

And for layout I think you have to follow theme HTML.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'category_name' => 'my-category-slug'
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post_parent' => $parent
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
  while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    // your loop
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Varsha Thanks for suggesstion.

Comment: I am not able to get Theme HTML please suggest.